# How to resize UIImageVIew based on content inside UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitextview

I have a UIImageView that has a UITextView within it's bounds and I want to resize the UIImageView based on the text inside the UITextView. How do I do this?

Here's what I've tried:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(MSChatCell *)cell andText:(NSString *)text isBlue:(BOOL)blue
{
    NSLog(@"changing height");
    UITextView *textView;
    PFImageView *chat;

    if(blue){
    CGRect newFrame = [text boundingRectWithSize:cell.blueText.bounds.size options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0],NSFontAttributeName, nil] context:nil];
    cell.blueText.frame = newFrame;
        cell.blueChat.frame = newFrame;

    }else{
        CGRect newFrame = [text boundingRectWithSize:cell.whiteText.bounds.size options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0],NSFontAttributeName, nil] context:nil];

        cell.whiteText.frame = newFrame;
        cell.whiteChat.frame = newFrame;
    }

}
```

where `cell.whiteChat` and `cell.blueChat` are UIImageViews and `cell.whiteText` and `cell.blueText` are UITextViews

Answer (score 0):

Well, calculating the size taken by your text and then creating a frame using it worked for me..

```
CGRect blueTextFrame = cell.blueText.frame;

CGRect blueChatFrame = cell.blueChat.frame;

CGSize textSize = [sample sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0]];

cell.blueTextFrame.size = textSize;

cell.blueChatFrame.size = textSize;
```

Similarly do it for the white one..

Comment: isn't CGFrame deprecated?

Comment: oh sorry.. I meant CGRect